# "Correct" way to install with only Cinnamon and sddm

Tags: cinnamon

New laptop, I want to install linux on this machine. I've tried a couple of window managers in a VM and settled on Cinnamon as wm and SDDM as DM.

I'd also prefer to have a Ubuntu like system as a base (for things like package manager and basically bigger community to search in case I have issues).

As far as I know, there are no distributions that have cinnamon as their installed window  (unless maybe Mint Cinnamon edition?).

I'd prefer not to have other window managers and too much additional crap that I won't use. So installing a full Ubuntu and then add cinnamon is not my preferred way to go.

Should I just install Ubuntu server (so that I don't install a window manager but have a base system) and then install cinnamon on top of that? Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: You are asking for opinions and those questions are subjective. https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask If you want a generic Linux answer please use https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Mint and the sorts are off topic as they never applied for official support from askubuntu.

Comment: *Should I just install Ubuntu server (so that I don't install a window manager but have a base system) and then install cinnamon on top of that? Or is that a bad idea?* -- If you know how to do it, then it is certainly not a bad idea. In case you want to know how to do it, ask a new question specifically about this.

Comment: FYI: Cinnamon is a DEsktop, and not a WindowManager. The Cinnamon DE uses the `muffin` WM (it used to be packaged separately, but packaging was combined for Debian & Ubuntu some time ago)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks. I'll try to be correct next time. Still trying to get my head around some of this terminology.

Comment: @Rinzwind I thought about this before asking the question and ended up deciding that "correct" way was technical enough since I don't expect there to be loads of ways to install a system without DE/WM and then install just one without ending up with a broken system. If you feel this is asking for opinions feel free to remove the question. Too bad this can't be asked/answers aren't appreciated here...

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Unless there are specific things I should watch out for besides installing the server version and then installing cinnamon, then I should be fine. Thank you for you answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the ubuntu cinnamon remix that has Ubuntu as core featuring the Cinnamon as desktop environment. The link is [here](https://ubuntucinnamon.org/)

Comment: we can only provide answers that use official Ubuntu. Other versions are off topic.

Comment: @Rinzwind So, just to be sure. If I want to post an additional question on this ubuntu cinnamon remix, I'm not supposed to do this here? Am I better of in the Ubuntu forum? SE Unix pages? I'm a bit reluctant to ask in a specific Ubuntu Cinnamon Remix crowd since answers there will likely be biased...

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here.  If/when Ubuntu Cinnamon *remix* becomes an official flavor, it'll be on-topic here. For now they provide their own support system (telegram group)

Comment: @guiverc Ok, thanks.

Comment: A form of this question has been asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465921&p=14053748#post14053748